# Converting an unsigned char array to jstring

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm having issues trying to convert an unsigned char array to jstring.

The context is I'm using a shared c library from Java.
So I'm implementing a JNI c++ file.
The function I use from the library returs a `unsigned char* num_carte_transcode`

And the function I implemented in the JNI C++ file returns a jstring.

So I need to convert the unsigned char array to jstring.

I tried this simple cast `return (env)->NewStringUTF((char*) unsigned_char_array);`

But though the array should only contain 20 bytes, I get randomly 22 or 23 bytes in Java...
(Though the 20 bytes are correct)

EDIT1: Here some more details with example

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_demo_DemoClass_functionToCall
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject, ) {
  // Here I define an unsigned char array as requested by the library function
  unsigned char unsigned_char_array[20];
  // The function feeds the array at execution
  function_to_call(unsigned_char_array);

  // I print out the result for debug purpose
  printf("result : %.*s (%ld chars)\n", (int) sizeof unsigned_char_array, unsigned_char_array, (int) sizeof unsigned_char_array);

  // I get the result I want, which is like: 92311221679609987114 (20 numbers)

  // Now, I need to convert the unsigned char array to jstring to return to Java
  return (env)->NewStringUTF((char*) unsigned_char_array);
  // Though... On debugging on Java, I get 21 bytes 92311221679609987114 (check the image below)
}
```

[image]

And sometimes I get 22 bytes, sometimes 23 ... though the expected result is always 20 bytes.

Comment: UTF-8 should be passed. As one java char or int code point can be more than 1 byte. Is the unsigned char* indeed 20 bytes long, and is the java `char[]` 20 long, that is 40 bytes, or what is exactly happening? There should probably be no problem with 7 bits ASCII.

Comment: Hello @JoopEggen. thanks for your quick reply. I edited the intial question to add more details :)

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Kindly share the input and the result as an array in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string passed to `NewStringUTF` must be null-terminated. The string you're passing, however, is not null-terminated, and it looks like there's some garbage at the end of the string before the first null.

I suggest creating a larger array, and adding a null terminator at the end:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_demo_DemoClass_functionToCall
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject recv) {
  unsigned char unsigned_char_array[20 + 1]; // + 1 for null terminator
  function_to_call(unsigned_char_array);    
  unsigned_char_array[20] = '\0'; // add null terminator

  printf("result : %s (%ld chars)\n", unsigned_char_array, (int) sizeof unsigned_char_array);

  return (env)->NewStringUTF((char*) unsigned_char_array); // should work now
}
```

Comment: Alright, that was it ! Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Something to note: `NewStringUTF()` expects **modified** UTF-8, so if `function_to_call()` outputs *standard* UTF-8 then `NewStringUTF()` won't work correctly for Unicode codepoint U+0000 or codepoints > U+FFFF. JNI doesn't have any functions that handle *standard* UTF-8, but you can use JNI to call a `String` constructor that accepts *standard* UTF-8 (this would also allow you to specify the actual byte count so you don't have to worry about the null terminator).